# I am a frequent traveller to the UK but recently got refused a visa because of discrepancies in my mother's birth date

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

During the past 7 years, I have been issued five UK visas (for 6 months and 2 years in length). I was recently refused because I wanted to travel with my mum. In my mother's passport and visa application is a different date of birth than what I have stated in my previous applications.

My mother is not literate and does not even remember when she was born. In processing her passport in my absence, officials determined her date of birth based on her narrative and events that happened in her early life.

What should I do, because I want to reapply?

Comment: She does not have a birth certificate? You need to either find it or legally create one based on other documents she has.

Comment: @kweku What exactly did the refusal letter say?

Comment: Onua Nana Kweku, scan your refusal letter, blog out your personal details and upload it in your question. Your situation is not strange. Hopefully they did not deny you based on misrepresentation. That’s not good.

Comment: Check for birth dates written in family bibles.

Comment: @zaph, family bibles are only usual in a limited number of cultures and almost certainly not where OP's mother comes from.

Comment: How much was the difference? If it was few days I would not understand, but if also the year changes, you should have some documents to reassure immigration that that person is really your mother. Any official document (also with wrong date) could help. E.g. your birth certificate maybe has the birth date of your mother, or the marriage certificate of your mother)

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn It seems you are the one bringing religion into the comments. I am not promoting any specific religion or religion in general. I provided a potential solution that potentially applies to many individuals. NB: I do not belong to any religious group.

Comment: Please upload a copy of the UK refusal letter. Closing as unclear until then.